# Big-Oh and Big-Omega?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have two question is about big $O$ and $\Omega$

if $g(n)$ is $O(n)$ is $g(n)$ $\Omega(n)$?

also

if $g(n)$ is $O(n)$ is $g(n)$ $\Omega(n^3)$?

if someone could do either one that would be great, so that I can do one on my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the function g(n)=1 is a counterexample.

Comment: how would that be true for $\Omega(n^3)$

Comment: couldn't 1 be multiplied 2n^3 to make g(n) $\Omega(n^3)$?